# How can i find and comment duplicates for large data in excel vba?

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

I have a code to find and highlight(entire row) duplicates based on the first column. Now I'm trying to copy the the last found comment an paste it to the located duplicate:

[image: example]

In this example the comment "Controle 1:OK" in row 8 should be copied and paste in row 10.
But with my code always the first comment "Controle 1: NOK" is copied and paste the comment in row 8 & 10.

I'm new in Excel VBA and just have a clue (put all found comments in an array and take the last comment) but don't know how to realize it.

Have someone an idea how to do this?

I'm using Excel 365.

```
 Sub sbFindDuplicatesInColumn()

    Dim lastRow As Long             
    Dim matchFoundIndex As Long
    Dim iCntr As Long               
    Dim comment As String

    lastRow = Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row

    For iCntr = 1 To lastRow
    If Cells(iCntr, 1) <> "" Then
        matchFoundIndex = WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(iCntr, 1), Range("A1:A" & lastRow), 0)
        comment = Cells(matchFoundIndex, 3).Value
        If iCntr <> matchFoundIndex Then

             Cells(iCntr, 3).Value = comment
             Range(Cells(iCntr, 1), Cells(iCntr, 3)).Font.Color = RGB(255, 40, 0)

       End If
    End If

    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: row 8 does not appear to be a duplicate. I see no duplicates.

Comment: i search duplicates with the firs column (Material-No). The material-no appears 3 times (row 5, 8 and 10). The material no in row 8 and 10 are duplicates of material- no in row 5

Comment: Ah.... I misread as you mean highlight entire row based on duplicates in first column.

Comment: No problem. I've edited my question :D

Comment: *Dim matchFoundIndex As* ... yes, what?

Comment: @peakpeak as Long. Sorry for the copy - paste mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this. 
 
It should loop all rows and look for duplicates in column "A". If duplicate found and no comment in duplicate row then last known comment is copied. 
 
If duplicate found but already has comment then this comment becomes new "last known" for further duplicates.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Dupes()

Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long, DupCounter As Long, DupPos As Long
Dim MatNo As String, Comment As String
Dim Found As Boolean
Dim ArrDuplicates() As Variant 'Declare dynamic array 

Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

'Redimennsion/change size of declared array 
ReDim ArrDuplicates(1 To 2, 1 To 1)

DupCounter = 1

With Ws
    'find last row with data in column "A" 
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    'Loop all rows from 1 to last 
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        'reset variables for each loop 
        Found = False
        DupPos = 0
        MatNo = .Cells(i, 1)
        Comment = .Cells(i, 3) 'Column 3 is column "C" if other 
                              'column to be used just change the number 
        'Search array with previous data and look for duplicates 
        For j = LBound(ArrDuplicates(), 2) To UBound(ArrDuplicates(), 2)
           'If material number currently checked found in array 
            If MatNo = ArrDuplicates(1, j) Then
                'If comment for current row is empty, take comment from array 
                If Trim(Comment) = "" Then
                    Comment = ArrDuplicates(2, j)
                End If
                'remember position of source data in array (first occurence
                'of material number)
                DupPos = j
                'set "Found" marker 
                Found = True
                'leave loop 
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j

        'if no duplicate found 
        If Not Found Then
            'redimension array. "Preserve" keyword added to keep values
            'already existing in array
            ReDim Preserve ArrDuplicates(1 To 2, 1 To DupCounter)
            'insert new data to array ((first occurance of material number) 
            ArrDuplicates(1, DupCounter) = MatNo
            ArrDuplicates(2, DupCounter) = Comment
            DupCounter = DupCounter + 1 'increase counter used to redimension array 
        Else  'if material number found in array 
            'if commnet variable is same as comment in array 
            'This means that comment of current row was empty  
            If Comment = ArrDuplicates(2, DupPos) Then
                .Cells(i, 3) = Comment 'put comment in current row and column 3 "C"
            Else
                'Commnet in current row was not empty and different than last one 
                'replace "last known comment" in array for material number 
                'with new one from current row 
                ArrDuplicates(2, DupPos) = Comment
            End If
            'change font colour 
            .Cells(i, 3).Font.Color = vbRed
        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Edit: Added some comments

[Check also ReDim Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/redim-statement)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This code is working fine. Now I'm trying to understand the code, some questions: "ReDim ArrDuplicates(1 To 2, 1 To 1)", "  ReDim Preserve ArrDuplicates(1 To 2, 1 To DupCounter)" what does these lines of code do ?  If I want to change the columns from the comments in column C to G, wich lines of code need an adaptation?

Comment: Added some comments.

Comment: Thank you for the comments !! This code is working perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying the input to this:

[image]

this is what you get, using the code below:

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMe()

    Dim wks As Worksheet: Set wks = Worksheets(1)
    Dim myLastRow As Long: myLastRow = lastRow(wks.Name)
    Dim matchRow As Long

    Dim myRow As Long
    For myRow = 1 To myLastRow
        With wks
            If .Cells(myRow, 1) <> "" Then
                matchRow = WorksheetFunction.Match(.Cells(myRow, 1), .Range("A1:A" & myLastRow), 0)
                If myRow <> matchRow Then
                    .Cells(myRow, 2) = .Cells(matchRow, 2)
                    .Cells(myRow, 2).Interior.Color = vbRed
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next myRow

    Debug.Print myLastRow

End Sub

Function lastRow(wsName As String, Optional columnToCheck As Long = 1) As Long

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets(wsName)
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, columnToCheck).End(xlUp).Row

End Function
```

It checks for duplicates on column `A` and whenever a duplicate is found, if it is not the first duplicate, it gets the comment of the first one. This is the check whether it is the first duplicate - `If myRow <> matchRow Then`

Comment: I don't want to simplify my input. The idea is to copy the last existing comment of every duplicate and paste it in the last duplicate.

Comment: Running your code does spot the duplicates but no comments are added

Comment: @ATI - the simplification of the input is done as a sample. Once you see how it works, you may find a way to edit it further.

Comment: @peakpeak - it has added the comments in red. With the line `                    .Cells(myRow, 2) = .Cells(matchRow, 2)`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Vityata thank you for your answer. I will try to get this with your code.